# Laravel 5.2 custom authorization action

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-request, laravel-authorization

I created User Controller policy. In User controller there is a method like this:

```
public function create(Request $request){

    $this->authorize($request->user());

    return view('frontpage');

}
```

Policy for this method works pretty fine, except one thing - If is action unauthorized, laravel fires this:

> This action is unauthorized.

Instead, I want it to fire 403 error. How to do this?

Comment: Try Overriding:

`public function forbiddenResponse()
    {
       return Response::make(view('errors.403'), 403);
    }`

Comment: Ill try, thanks, but where I can find method you mentioned?

Comment: Just ignore my last comment and try this `if($this->authorize($request->user())){ App::abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');} else { return view('frontpage'); }` if it works for you.

Comment: The first approach would be a better Idea, because it would make my desired abort(403) as default. The second approach would make my controller much more cumbersome.

Comment: You have to extend your abstract class e.g `Request` from `FormRequest` and in `Request` class override `forbiddenResponse()`

Comment: I found App\Http\Requests\Request.php - here is Request class extending FormRequest. I wrote in this class following:     public function forbiddenResponse(){
  dd("boo");
    }
 
 Sadly, it looks like nothing changed. I am gettin still the same response.